# Why Daka attended "Saints Among Us" school project instead of hospital?

Tags: plot-explanation, st-vincent

In *St. Vincent (2014)*, Daka who is pregnant Russian sex worker and close friend
to Vincent. One day Daka's water got broke. On the way to hospital with Vincent. She visited "Saints Among Us" school project first to watch Oliver's speech instead of reaching hospital.

[image]

Why she took risk in reaching "Saints Among Us" school project?

Comment: she just wanted vincent (Bill Murray) to see the speech coz its about him